# Async/await implementation

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I need help in async/await implementation. In my code, I want a clear button to clear everything and reload the page. I want to set this up as a promise such that only when it is fulfilled, will it send a get request to the JSON server and get the posts from the JSON server and store them in local storage.
I have set up a `console.log` message to pop up when the promise is resolved. Now the problem I am experiencing is this message appears and the data is fetched first then the page reload happens after. I thought the page reload would happen first and only then will the message appear and the data would get fetched. this makes the code not to function as I want. I don't know if it is the way I have set up the Promise. I hope my problem is understood. Someone help, I promise to upvote your answer and account :)

```
const UISelectors =uisetup.getSeletor(); //gets html classes and ids from another module
document.querySelector(UISelectors.clearBtn).addEventListener('click', clearAll); //calls event

const clearAllData = async function(){

    //This is the promise supposed to be waited on
    const clears = new Promise((resolve)=>{
        itemsetup.clearAll();
        uisetup.clearEverything()
        storagesetup.clearAllfromStorage()
        const addAllItems = 0
        uisetup.theTotaldatas(addAllItems)
        uisetup.clearEditState()
        location.reload()
        resolve('Finished clearing')
    })
    const storagedata = await clears
    return storagedata
}

//Function for the clear button event
function clearAll(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    //Calls the function after it has been completed
    clearAllData()
    .then(clearmessage=> {
        http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts')
        .then(posts => {
            storagesetup.storeinStorage(posts)
            uisetup.populateItems(posts)
            let datas=null
            posts.forEach(post =>{
            datas += post.datas
            })
            uisetup.theTotaldatas(datas)
            console.log(posts)
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
        console.log(clearmessage)

    })
}
```

Comment: A page reload stops the current page from doing anything including suspending and stopping all your Javascript.  So, you can't make reloading the page part of a continuous set of operations in your page's Javascript.  You could do everything else and then trigger the reload as your last step.  Otherwise, you will have to somehow make the script resume when the new page is loaded.  That will mean you have to pass some state to the new page reload often done as a query parameter that your  script can see when the new page loads and that will tell the script where to pick up executing.

Comment: Also wrapping a bunch of synchronous operations in a promise accomplishes nothing useful.  Promises are used to monitor asynchronous operations and they must be explicitly hooked into asynchronous completion events/callbacks to be able to do anything useful.  Also, they have no magic powers to somehow just know when asynchronous operations are done.  Instead, they have to be told when asynchronous operations are done via callbacks or events.  And, they don't work across page reloads because any promise created before the page reload is destroyed by the browser when a new page takes its place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It has shone a new light on the matter. I clearly had not understood the concepts well. the only reason i used promises was because of that page reload but by your explanation i guess i will have to rewrite the code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the following part I can say that you believe your JS process resumes after page reload.

```
    location.reload()
    resolve('Finished clearing')
```

This is not so. It works the other way round. That is - you create a page load hook which will execute when a page reloads and call your promise in there, take any action after the promise is resolved.

```
<body onload="clearAll()">
```

Let this function fetch data and store it in the local storage. You will have to modify your function accordingly.

Comment: This is a great idea. only problem is that i wanted to call the clearAll function only when I click the clear button and not anytime the page reloads...and I wanted the page to reload (or something like a page reload to happen) when I click the clear button. I have realised that the problem is that my code is gibberish and I will have to rewrite it. But i will just leave this question up in case any beginner comes across it to read your comments.

Comment: The solution is to fetch your data, save them in the storage, and just reload the page - all at the button click. Don't expect anything to resume after the page reload. Once reloaded, its a whole new process. I will leave the answer to highlight this order.

Comment: The main issue is i was trying to kill two birds with one stone.  That is I was trying to get data from localstorage and store in the api server if the data is not in the api.... and if the data is not in localstorage but in the api then i wanted to get the data from the api and store in localstorage...if i can send you the whole code i think you will slap me in the face, maybe... this is just a piece of it...and i am also using vanilla javascript without react or any framework